# SSIS Flat File - CSV formatting not working for multi-line fileds

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I want to import *.csv file. There is head row with the column names, and data rows below. The problem is in column `description`.This column has multi-line text and each line is recognised as the record.

Document has `{CR}{LF}` for the end of row, and `{LF}` for the end of line in multi-line text. Like this:

```
(0)"Name","Description" {CR}{LF}
(1)"John","adsaddsadas" {CR}{LF}
(2)"Mike","dasdsadsdsda
dsadadsdasdsa {LF}
dsadadsadsad {LF}
dasdsadsadsd"{CR}{LF}
(3)"Dave","dsada"{CR}{LF}
```

It returns an error saying the row (2) is truncated and is missing data

I have selected `{CR}{LF}` as delimiter, but it still recognises this as 6 records instead of 3, i suppose it, for some reason, recognises `{LF}` as row delimiter.

Is there anyone who had similar issue here, or knows how to get over this.

Also i want to mention i don't have a lot of experience with this, so i don't know if there is data missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your flat file connection manager make sure that the `Header Row Delimiter` is set to `{CR}{LF}`

[image]

And That the `Row Delimiter` is also set to `{CR}{LF}`

[image]

And Check that `Description` Column has a length of `4000` *(to prevent text from getting truncated)* and that the last column delimiter is `{CR}{LF}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works now. 
Just to mention for someone who might face the same problem, the key thing for me was setting column length to 4000. I was trying all the possible combinations with the file versions and delimiters, without thinking of this